# Tkinter Entry Widget - Error if Entry is not an int

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering how I can display an error if the entry is not an integer.
I was able to make it so my code will only accept a certain range of integers, but I don't have a way to display an error if letters are given instead. I was wondering if someone can shed some knowledge.. Thanks!

```
def get(self):
    c = int(self.a.get())
    d = int(self.b.get())
    if c>255 or c<0 or d>255 or d<0 :
        print c
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Error2", "Please enter a value between 0-255")
        self.clicked_wbbalance()
    if c<255 and c>0 and d<255 and d>0:
        print "it worked"
        pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.isdigit()` to check whether the input is integer or not:

```
In [5]: "123".isdigit()
Out[5]: True

In [7]: "123.3".isdigit()
Out[7]: False

In [8]: "foo".isdigit()
Out[8]: False
```

so you code becomes something like this:

```
def get(self):
    c = self.a.get()
    d = self.b.get()
    if c.isdigit() and d.isdigit():
        c,d=int(c),int(d)
        if c>255 or c<0 or d>255 or d<0 :
            print c
            tkMessageBox.showerror("Error2", "Please enter a value between 0-255")
            self.clicked_wbbalance()
        elif c<255 and c>0 and d<255 and d>0:
            print "it worked"
            pass
    else:
         print "input is not an integer"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the exception when there is invalid input.

```
try:
    c = int(self.a.get())
    d = int(self.b.get())
except ValueError:
    # Show some sort of error message, input wasn't integers
else:
    # Input was integers, continue as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...you can always format your strings, like this for example:

```
msg = "Error. Invalid value %d. Value must be between 0-255" % c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 123
if isinstance(num, int):
True
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking to check whether the input string is integer or not, before conversion to int.

Comment: There are no converting here... just an eg how the isinstance work.

Comment: but what's the use of showing an example of `isinstance()` here?